# How to see this two-arm spiral structure in the vector field $\vec{V}=(x\cos{2rt}+y\sin{2rt})\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, vectors, graphing-functions, vector-fields

Consider the following 2D vector field on the $xy$-plane
$$\vec{V}=(x\cos{2rt}+y\sin{2rt})\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.
When plotting the vector's angle $\arctan(V_x,V_y)\in[-\pi,\pi]$ by color on the $xy$-plane, it always clearly shows a spiral pattern ($t=10$ in the plot below). How can I prove the appearance of the two spirals?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spiral boundaries are the points where the scalar factor $x\cos 2rt + y\sin 2rt$ changes sign. That makes the direction of the final vector jump by $\pi$, and so the color changes abruptly.

$x\cos 2rt + y\sin 2rt$ is the dot product product $(x,y)\cdot(\cos 2rt,\sin 2rt)$. This is $0$ when the direction of $(x,y)$ differs by $\pi/2$ from $2rt$, so in polar coordinates the zeroes are at
$$ \theta = 2rt \pm \pi/2 $$
You get a double [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral) whose windings are $\pi/2t$ apart.